# Should I put my Blockchain behind an API?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am using a Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain.

My blockchain is "private", which means only people we accept can participate.

Right now, the blockchain is open to Internet. Is it safe ?

Should I put my Blockchain behind an API that would be in charge of Read / Write operations ?

From the "data certification" point of view, less steps between data and blockchain, the better.

Does it make sense in a security point of view ?

Comment: The best security is making it unusable.

Comment: like that ? https://github.com/kelseyhightower/nocode

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean by blockchain being opened to internet.

If you are referring to the data structure of blocks forming a chain, it's just some files stored in `peer` component. If you want to discuss about it being opened, I'd rather see it as a `peer` component being opened to the internet.

If you manage to protect the `peer` component from illegal access, the only legal access `Fabric` provides you is through using correctly authorized certificate, so from that point on, I wouldn't worry that much.

Putting API middleware in front of the blockchain, however will provide easier interface for other users. From realistic implementation point of view, those interface will be required to some point, so it should better be protected from other security threats.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is to create a "standard" API for your network. This would be an app which can request for and store crypto from the CA and provides some sort of authentication mechanism to allow authorized users to then use that crypto to make requests to the network.

When you begin onboarding users to your network, you need to give them the option of using your standard API or making their own. This gives them the convenience to get started quickly by using a pre-built solution with the freedom to build their own interface into the network if they would like to.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, the blockchain is open to Internet. Is it safe ?

First of all, Blockchain is secure because of its design. Blockchains stores data using certain rules that are extremely difficult for attackers to manipulate. As the numbers of block grows, it will be harder for attacker to manipulate the old block.

**However**, although we have a **super secure blockchain** system, we can't control the security of each user account or third party system.
That's why most of the security breaches in public blockchain are happening on the third party system or because of human error **(not inside the blockchain)**.

> Should I put my Blockchain behind an API that would be in charge of
>   Read / Write operations ?

API can be seen as a "bridge" between blockchain and us. Of course, we need this bridge to read / write Transactions to blockchain. It doesn't matter what bridge are you using, as long you can ensure the security of your bridge design.

> From the "data certification" point of view, less steps between data
>   and blockchain, the better. Does it make sense in a security point of
>   view ?

One of the **important aspect private blockchain** is about *limiting who can access into a blockchain*. By limiting the user interaction, we can reduce the potential of security breach. So, the risk of having security breach can be reduced.